# What does `composes` on styles

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit and one of the view I can see this code

```
// src/views/HomeView/HomeView.scss:5
.counter--green {
  composes: counter;
  color: rgb(25,200,25);
}

// src/views/HomeView/HomeView.js:45
<span className={classes['counter--green']}>{this.props.counter}</span>
```

I'm wondering what does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [CSS modules syntax](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#composition) for including the styles from another rule.

In this case it adds the styles from the `counter` rule, to the `counter--green` rule.

With regular CSS we'd have to write BEM-style classes this way.

```
.counter {
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}

.counter--green {
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
}
```

Then apply them to elements together.

```
<div class="counter counter--green"></div>
```

By composing the block style into the modifier style, we can remove the redundant class name.

```
.counter--green {
  composes: counter;
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
}
```

Then all we need is the modifier class.

```
<div class="counter--green"></div>
```

Unlike the normal pre-processor mixin model, the styles aren't duplicated in the compiled CSS. Instead the output class for `counter--green` will be the composition of both classnames and the rendered version will actually have the same effect as writing `counter counter--green`.

Comment: Hey Dan! It doesn't add the styles, it adds the imported class name to its exports. The output class for `.counter--green` will actually become `.counter .counter--green`. This is especially helpful when composing across modules: since it references the class name's key, it will correctly output the hashed class name for both class names.